# OpenStreetMap Multilingual Labels

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm rendering OpenStreetMap data from a Postgresql/gis db using Geoserver 2.8. Initially I was seeing issues in China and Japan where the place name labels were appearing as boxes instead of text. I added DroidSans and DroidSansFallback fonts to the Geoserver styles directory and modified the sld by adding the fonts. This fixed a lot of the labels, however in western China I am still seeing some labels composed of boxes along with characters. It appears that these are multilingual labels.
Has anyone seen this and found an effective workaround?